# Show that $ \exists \ c \in (a,b) \ $ such that $ \ f(b)-f(a)=cf'(c) \ln (\frac{b}{a}) \ $

Tags: derivatives

Let $ \ f \ $ be a function continuous on $ \ [a,b] \ $ and differentiable on $ \ (a,b) \ \ and \ \ 0 <a <b. $

Show that $ \exists \ c \in (a,b) \ $ such that $ \ f(b)-f(a)=cf'(c) \ln (\frac{b}{a}) \ $

**Answer:**

By Mean Value theorem , $ \ \exists \ \xi \in (a,b) \ $ such that

$ \ f(b)-f(a)=f'(\xi) (b-a) \ $

**But how to prove the given equation?**

**Help me**

Answer (score 2):

There is a generalized version of the mean value theorem that says that if $f$ and $g$ are functions continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $g(b)\ne g(a)$, then there is a $c\in(a,b)$ such that
$$
\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}
$$
(notice that $c$ is the same for both $f$ and $g$, which is stronger than if we had applied the mean value theorem to $f$ and $g$ separately and divided one equality by the other). Now use that theorem with $g(x)=\ln x$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Look at the function $g:\left[\ln a,\ln b\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as

$$g\left(x\right)\equiv f\left(e^{x}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

If we look at 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{\ln b-\ln a}=\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\dfrac{b-a}{\ln b-\ln a}=\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\dfrac{e^{\ln b}-e^{\ln a}}{\ln b-\ln a},
\end{align*}
so this suggests the matter of chain rule applied to $f(e^{u})$ at points $\ln a,\ln b$, and yes, Mean Value Theorem does the job for the rest.